How to correctly pass nvarchar parameter to SQL Stored Procedure from .NET Application?
I would like to execute a SQL stored procedure (SP) with parameters. However, I am having difficulties passing nvarchar (string) parameter called "office" to the SP.
If I want to execute the SP directly on the MS SQL, I need to add double single quote to make it work. That's why I added double single quote on the "office" parameter on the code. However it also did not work.
CODE:
parameters.Add("office", "''Niederlassung Nord''"); //<---THIS IS THE ISSUE
parameters.Add("year", "2023");
ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[sqlConn];

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(settings.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand storedCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                storedCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                storedCmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> value in parameters)
                    {
                        storedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + value.Key, value.Value);
                    }
                }

                using (SqlDataReader reader = storedCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, string> row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) // one field
                            {
                                row.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i].ToString());//getname is used to get column name
                            }
                            currentList.Add(row);
                        }
                    }             
                }
            }
        }

SQL
USE [ServerName]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetData]
        @office = N'''Niederlassung Nord''', //<-- works only if I add double single quote like this
        @year= N'2023'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO

The error I got is:

Incorrect Syntax near 'Nord'.

I got also the same error when I remove the double single quote on the code or if I pass parameter without a whitespace.
How do I resolve this?
EDIT
Stored Procedure
USE [ServerName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
  @office nvarchar(4000) = null,
  @year nvarchar(4) = null
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #masterData2 (
    [office] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
)
...
  if (@office is not null)
        begin
            if (@sql1 is not null)
                select @sql1 += ' AND #masterData2.[office ] in (' + @office + ')'
            else
                select @sql1 = ' #masterData2.[office ] in (' + @office + ')'
        end
...


You should start by using Parameters.Add, then you can be explicit in the data type you are passing. Though, Parameters.AddWithValue always assumes a string is a Unicode value (hence why it's a problem).

"<-- works only if I add double single quote like this" That has a smell of that the procedure suffers from injection. That is likely the real problem. Also why are you passing @year as an nvarchar, surely it's an int, no?

You don't have to do anything to pass a parameter value. If you have quoting issues it means GetData is not using the parameter as a parameter but concatenating it with other strings to construct a SQL query. We can't guess what's wrong without the code.

Can you post the definition of your procedure dbo.GetData?

@ThomA Added the SP variable definition. Is that enough? Btw I'm not the one who created the SP. I only use it. However, it worked before with another SP that also uses nvarchar.

... is not a helpful definition of a procedure... The definition you've given us is like someone asking you "Can you tell me your address please?" and you reply with "127", as that's your door number.

If everything works, why are you asking the question? Of course it's not enough to add definition, you have to add whole procedure. As thom says, it probably contains a bug or some kind of concatenation

@ThomA added more information related to the parameter on the SP, though I still think it's not enough. Unfortunately, I cannot post the whole SP definition here as it contains company information. I'm just a developer on the .NET side. who's only trying to use the SP. Is there anything I can ask to the SQL developer related to this issue? Because you said it has something related to injection?

' AND #masterData2.[office ] in (' + @office + ')' well that's a concern. Why are you injecting the parameters and not parametrising them? Are you using dynamic SQL to be able to pass a list? Why not use a table type parameter?

@ThomA I don't know how to answer your question as I don't make the SP and I'm not familiar with SQL... but the user can insert multiple values into 'office' and we pass the parameter like for example ''south'',''east'' something like that. Is this what you mean with table type parameter? https://www.sqlshack.com/table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server/

Seems like you should be talking the developer of the SP, and they should be fixing the massive injection issue in it then, @user2018 . I dread to think what would happen if you passed an office's "name" as NULL); CREATE LOGIN NewSA WITH PASSWORD = '1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sa ADD MEMBER NewSA; --

If you are using CommandType.StoredProcedure then you only pass the name of the procedure, nothing else (no EXEC no parameters), and the SqlCommand will pass the parameters for you.

Issue with your code is due to escape characters. You need to update Code to add the parameter office. Do not use two single quotes ''. In case of Code, you do not need to escape single quote ' character by writing it twice like ''. Try like below.
parameters.Add("office", "'Niederlassung Nord'")

You mentioned in your question that while you try it on SQL like below and it worked. In case of SQL, if you want to use single quote in string then it can be escaped by doubling them up (like ''). You can refer this.
@office = N'''Niederlassung Nord''', //<-- works only if I add double single quote like this


Thank you. It worked. I honestly thought that I had tried this.
